# Scaling loop cuts gets distorted both in local and global z axis in my mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, transforms

I am adding three loop cuts in a shape and I want them to scale them on the Z axis to get them closer. [image: 3 loop cuts]
When I press S + Z + Z to scale them on the local Z axis, instead of moving locally, the entire mesh starts distorting from multiple sides. Like this:
[image: distorted scale]
How do I bring the three loop cuts closer in Z direction without distorting the mesh?

Comment: It seems you have some hidden geometry (maybe some duplicated extrusions). Try selecting all vertices and merge by distance to get rid of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

It seems like you're trying to scale it down with the bounding box as the pivot. Which means scale around basically this enter mass and it's center.

[image: Bounding box visualization]

Instead of thinking about scaling these edge loops down, try thinking of it as scaling down the edge rings that bind them together.

[image: Edge rings instead of edge loops]

You can set the pivot to "Individual Origins" to scale each separate element in it's own bounding box

[image: Individual elements pivot]

which ALMOST works except for these angled parts right here:

[image: Bad scaling in certain areas]

So last thing, change the transform orientation to "Normal" which basically means "Scale an element around which way it's facing".

[image: Normal transform select menu location]

Usually we think of normals in regards to faces, where Z is pointing directly away from the faces, and the XY axes are running parallel to the plane of the face.

[image: Normal face orientation axes]

But edges and vertices have normals too.

Once we do that, piece of cake.

[image: Scaling individual edgerings spacing]

In a scenario like this too you could also just ask if it's even worth it to fiddle with something like this, and consider just dissolving the messed up part and re-insetting it to your desired size. Sometimes just redoing something is quicker than trying to manually correct a mistake.

[image: redoing a messed up part]

I think in this situation both are fairly easy, just figured I'd present a range of options.